# Select and apply correct model from different data frame using purrr

Tags: r, purrr, modelr

In my data, I have correlated data (diet and liver) for 50+ different compounds (simplified here).

```
library(tidyverse)
Sigma <- matrix(.7, nrow=6, ncol=6) + diag(6)*.3
vars_tr <- data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n=10, mu=c(2:7), Sigma=Sigma))

tr<-tibble(
  compound=c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C",10)),
  diet=c(vars_tr$X1, vars_tr$X2, vars_tr$X3),
  liver=c(vars_tr$X4, vars_tr$X5, vars_tr$X6))
```

Following the guidance on doing regressions for multiple models, I created a nested data frame and stored the output (learning this method this week was a lifesaver!).

```
model<-function(df){lm(data=df, liver~diet)}

mods<- tr %>%
  group_by(compound) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model=map(data, model))
```

Now I have new 'diet' data for which no 'liver' data exists.

```
new<-tibble(
  compound=c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C",10)),
  diet=c(rnorm(10, 4), rnorm(10, 5), rnorm(10,6)))
```

What I would like to do is take advantage of purrr generate a liver concentration for each diet concentration using the correct model for the compound. My best attempt looks like:

```
preds<-function(c, x){    
  add_predictions(tibble(diet=x), filter(mods, compound==c)$model[[1]], 'liver')$liver
}

new%>%
  mutate(liver=map2(compound, diet, preds))
```

which returns an error.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

EDIT 6/4/2020:

Based on the helpful comments from Bruno and Ronak Shah below, I've made some progress but haven't found the solution. Both suggest joining the models to the existing table, which makes way more sense than what I was doing.

Based on that, it is relatively simple to do the following:

```
new_mods<-
  new%>%
  group_by(compound)%>%
  nest()%>%
  left_join(., select(mods_d, compound, model), , by='compound')%>%
  mutate(predicts = map2(data, model, add_predictions))%>%
  unnest(predicts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join operation and keep working on tibbles

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

Sigma <- matrix(.7, nrow=6, ncol=6) + diag(6)*.3
vars_tr <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=10, mu=c(2:7), Sigma=Sigma))

tr<-tibble(
  compound=c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C",10)),
  diet=c(vars_tr$X1, vars_tr$X2, vars_tr$X3),
  liver=c(vars_tr$X4, vars_tr$X5, vars_tr$X6))

model<-function(df){lm(data=df, liver~diet)}

mods<- tr %>%
  nest_by(compound) %>% 
  mutate(model = list(model(data)))

new<-tibble(
  compound=c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C",10)),
  diet=c(rnorm(10, 4), rnorm(10, 5), rnorm(10,6)))

new_nest <- new %>% 
  nest_by(compound)

results <- mods %>% 
  left_join(new_nest,by = "compound") %>% 
  mutate(predicts = list(predict(model,data.y)))
```

Comment: I'm not finding nest_by as a function in the tidyverse.

Comment: nest_by is in the dplyr version 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for prediction :

```
preds<-function(data, mod){   
   modelr::add_predictions(data, mod)$liver
}
```

`nest` the dataframe for each `compound`, join with `mods` and apply the respective model for each group of data.

```
library(dplyr)
new %>%
   tidyr::nest(data = diet) %>%
   left_join(mods, by = 'compound') %>%
   mutate(liver = purrr::map2(data.y, model, preds))


# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  compound data.x            data.y            model  liver     
#  <chr>    <list>            <list>            <list> <list>    
#1 A        <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <dbl [10]>
#2 B        <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <dbl [10]>
#3 C        <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <dbl [10]>
```

Based on the requirement you can `select` relevant columns and `unnest` the results if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, nest(data=diet) won't work for my data set because it actually contains many other columns of data that, while not included in the model, I need to preserve. If I nest everything but compound, I can't find a way to make map2 pull the correct column as input.

Comment: @aleoconn You should include that in the post, it is not possible for us to know that you have additional columns in your data if you don't mention it. The answer above works for the data you have provided in your post. Moreover, you can always `select` columns before you `nest` them. If you have trouble implementing the answer please update your post with relevant or similar sample data so that we can help.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I updated my post with the solution that ended up working.